# The transitivity of the action of the group of diffeomorphisms generated by a transitive framing

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Suppose we have a smooth manifold $M$ and $L \subseteq \Gamma(TM)$ an $\mathbb{R}$-vector subspace, such that the map $M \times L \rightarrow TM$ given by $(x, X) \rightarrow X_x$ is a vector bundle isomorphism; this is called a framing.

We are assuming that the group $G_L = \{ f \in Diff(M): f_* X = X , \ \forall X \in L \}$ acts transitively on $M$ via $f x = f(x)$ for any $x \in M, f \in G_L$. In this case, it turns out the vector fields in $L$ are complete. I don't think $G_L$ plays a further part in my question, though, so we might as well just assume the vector fields in $L$ are complete.

Let $\Gamma_L := \{ \phi^X : X \in L \}$, where $(t \in \mathbb{R}, x \in M) \mapsto \phi^X_t (x)$  is the current of the vector field $X$. $\Gamma_L$ also acts on $M$. I am trying to see why the orbits $\Gamma_L x \stackrel{def}{=} \{ \phi^{X}_t(x): X \in L, t\in \mathbb{R} \}$ are closed. The source I am reading ([here](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/jeber_02/talks/lieIII.pdf) , Theorem 2, beginning of Ad 2. ) says this follows by abstract nonsense, but I don't see why.

I tried using the fact that $M \times L \rightarrow TM$ is an isomorphism, so for a fixed $x \in $M, for any $v \in T_xM$ there's one and only one $X \in L$ s.t. $X_x = v$, together with the fact that $\phi_t^X(x) = \phi_1^{tX}(x)$, but I can't see how either of the two help.